# jQuery dilemma in loading different pages on one page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

Hello i need some help to figure out what to do .

I am trying to create a page that has a list of events and each time I click one of the list's elements a different photo gallery should load. I did this by loading each gallery in a different iframe.

The problem is that right now the only thing it dose is loading the first galery and the other ones don't seem to manage loading any pictures (if I refresh each frame than they work fine)

What should i do?

This is the script I used in the webpage

You can find the page source here http://www.avantsolutions.ro/exp.txt

Comment: Any reason why you picked an iframe?

Comment: Mihai is not fond of jQuery :)

Comment: @Kyle:i picked an iframe because it's easier to load custom webpages in to them . . . . .

Comment: @Suresh S: it's not that i am not fond of jquery it's just that if i don't use jquery in the main page the rest of the pages work fust fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery's `load` function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load a gallery via ajax.

`$(selectorForYourGalleryDisplayDiv).load( url, [ data ], [ complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ] )`

Load will take the result from `url`, if you need to pass it `data` it will use a HTTP POST, and replace the inner html of the wrapped set it is called on.

I don't know the internals of your architecture, but the main process is giving your galleries Ids, pass them to the server using the [JSON format](http://www.json.org/), your code will use that id to get what's needed for the gallery, render the html and return it.

`load` will drop that html into the elements that match `selectorForYourGalleryDisplayDiv`.

Comment: i don't quite understand an you give me an example please?

Comment: i cant figure out how to use what you gave me. or if you could just tell me how to reload a i frame

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [jQuery UI Plugin](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/) instead of iFrame.
On clicking of list item(West pane), you can load center pane div with corresponding images.
Check the examples [here](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos.cfm).

Comment: i cant figure out how to use what you gave me. or if you could just tell me how to reload a i frame